# Sql join shows null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, inner-join

I have 2 sql tables mtblSite_Lavel_Budget and mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel. I want to join them, so I wrote the query below, but one column always give null result although there are values in that field.

[image]

[image]

Query is as below

```
select mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.SFTI_Id, 
mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Site_Lavel_Interventions, 
mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Sub_Site_Lavel_Interventions,
mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Bill_No, mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Date_Of_Bill,
mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Eligible_Exp,
mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Non_Eligible_Exp,
mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Total,
mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Physical_Progress,
mtblSite_Lavel_Budget.Sanction_Amount_DPR  
from mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel 
left join mtblSite_Lavel_Budget 
   on mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Sub_Site_Lavel_Interventions= mtblSite_Lavel_Budget.Sub_Site_Lavel_Interventions 
WHERE mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.SFTI_Id =13 
ORDER BY Date_Of_Bill desc
```

and the result is as below

[image]

Please advise regarding the issue.

Comment: The reason it gives nulls is because the join didn't return any results, ie. you didn't get the rows in the joined table; basically, your join clause is wrong. Your code doesn't give enough information for any further help, I'm affraid.

Comment: could you please elaborate? why this join is wrong?

Comment: these are nvarchar values

Comment: @Gaurav. The values in `mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Sub_Site_Lavel_Interventions` and  `mtblSite_Lavel_Budget.Sub_Site_Lavel_Interventions` are not equal, so your join doesn't return anything from the second table

Comment: you left join is fecthing all records from mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel regardless of a match on mtblSite_Lavel_Budget .  as such no matchs bring back nulls

Comment: check that the fields your matching actually do match and post results

Comment: the joint condition "on mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.Sub_Site_Lavel_Interventions= mtblSite_Lavel_Budget.Sub_Site_Lavel_Interventions" is that correct?

Comment: Basically, given your data, there are no rows in `mtblSite_Lavel_Budget` that have a `Sub_Site_Lavel_Interventions` of `Distribution panelling`, for example.

Comment: then what should I do. If I do like " from mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel left join  mtblSite_Lavel_Budget on 
       mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.sfti_id = mtblSite_Lavel_Budget.sfti_id ".
 
it show records but it shows double records, I mean instead of two records it shows 4 (2 duplicate records)

Comment: That's probably because stfi_id means something else than you think. The way it seems to me, `NULL` is the proper value to return in that column, since there's no relevant data in the budget table. If the only thing that bothers you is the fact that there's a `NULL` instead of `0`, you can use `coalesce(mtblSite_Lavel_Budget.Sanction_Amount_DPR, 0) as [Sanction_Amount_DPR]` instead of just `mtblSite_Lavel_Budget.Sanction_Amount_DPR`.

Comment: but still same results

Comment: Put what you're trying to do into words. You're being very unclear about your objective, and why the results you get are not the results you expect. What would you like to have in that column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   from mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel left join  mtblSite_Lavel_Budget on 
       mtblExpenditure_Site_Lavel.sfti_id = mtblSite_Lavel_Budget.sfti_id
```

I think its confused becouse you are joining on a string column its always best to join on the id where posible.

Comment: it show records but it shows double records, I mean instead of two records it shows 4 (2 duplicate records)

Comment: it's a problem with our keys, if you have an incomplete join it can duplicate value. Do you have another key you could link (sno_id ?) else if you are forced to link on string, it's not perfect but it could be possible. In your schema if you have alpha numero column try to save them as char(x) not varchar and never max! when comparing take care to do upper if it's case sensitive and you are scared about that error, Ltrim and rtrim to be sure not annoyed with blank... and finaly take an example which should work and check your key manualy if it's an error from you or your data